# Unable to make the right query in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to group by  name then find the percentage of count of fill document to total document. The data is given below,here(fill:0 means not fill):-

```
{"name":"Raj","fill":0}
{"name":"Raj","fill":23}
{"name":"Raj","fill":0}
{"name":"Raj","fill":43}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":0}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":23}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":0}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":43}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":43}
{"name":"Rahul","fill":43}
```

Result :-

```
{
  "name":"Raj",
   fillcount:2,
   fillpercentagetototaldocument:50%  // 2 (fill count except 0 value )  divide by 4(total document for raj)
}
{
  "name":"Rahul",
   fillcount:4,
   fillpercentagetototaldocument:66%   // 4(fill count except 0 value )  divide by 6(total document for rahul)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want you use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation) combined with a conditional count like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      fillcount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $ne: [
                "$fill",
                0
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      fillcount: 1,
      fillpercentagetototaldocument: {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$fillcount",
              "$total"
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K8YF8d6liCY)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongos aggregation function to achieve that.
example:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { name: '$name'},
          fillpercentagetototaldocument: { $sum: '$fill' },
          fillCount:{$sum:1}
        },
      },
      { $sort: { fillpercentagetototaldocument: -1 } },

    ]);
```

The result will look like this afterwards:

```
[
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Rahul"
    },
    "fillpercentagetototaldocument" : 152,
    "fillCount" : 6.0
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Raj"
    },
    "fillpercentagetototaldocument" : 66,
    "fillCount" : 4.0
}
]
```

Comment: fillpercentagetototaldocument,We are calculating the percentage over fill to total but I think You are sum all the fill field.